# If $\mu$ is a signed, finite Borel measure on $[0,1]$, is there $a \in (0,1)$ such that $\mu([a,1]) \neq 0$?

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $\mu \neq 0$ be a signed, finite Borel measure on $[0,1]$ that is not concentrated at $0$.

> Does there exists $a \in (0,1)$ such that $\mu([a,1]) \neq 0$?

If there is no such $a$, then $\mu((b,c)) = 0$ for all $b,c \in (0,1)$, hence $\mu(A) = 0$ for all Borel sets in $[0,1]$, but does this imply that $\mu = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is no such $a$. Then $\mu [a,b)=0$ whenever $a< b <1$ which implies $\mu (A)=0$ for every Borel set $A \subseteq (0,1)$. [Finite disjoint unions of half closed intervals $[a,b)$ form an algebra which generates the Borel sigma algebra. By Uniqueness part of Cartheodory Extension Theorem we get $\mu (A)=0$ for every Borel set $A $ in $(0,1)$].  Also $\mu \{1\}=\lim \mu (1-\frac 1  n ,1]=0$. So $\mu$ is  concentrated on $\{0\}$ which is a contradiction .

Comment: The line "which implies $\mu(A)=0$ for every Borel set $A$" needs a proof. This may invoke Dynkin $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Thank you for the comment. Since $\pi -\lambda$ theorem is only known to probabilists I have added as proof using Caratheodory Extension Theorem.